# Update CCK Field Every 90 Days

Tags: rules

I'm using Drupal 7. I have a CCK field called Placement Date (Placement_Date) that the end user will manually put in. I then have two text fields, Start_of_Period and End_of_Period. Start_of_Period initially is set to Field->Placement_Date and Field->End_of_Period is set to 90 days out. The setup is no problem, but after 90 days Field->Start_of_Period needs to be the old End_of_Period + 1, and Field->End_of_Period needs to be another 90 days out from the new Field->Start_of_Period. I looked to Rules to try to find a way to schedule this, but cannot figure out what I need to be doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> - You need to [set up cron tab](http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DOCS/Setting+up+a+server+cron+or+scheduled+task) on your server may be once a day
> - use [hook_cron()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to add your custom code write query to grab nids for which field values needs to be updated.
> - use node_load_multiple() to load all nodes with the query returned nids
> - update the field values and save the node again in a loop.
> - set the crontab to run at the time when your site receives least traffic, this way it will not be performance issue as well.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.


I think this would be great if we weren't already running cron. We currently have cron running for reindexing and updating another portion of the site. It looks like hook_cron() will check/update the necessary fields every time cron runs, which is a few times a day already. I worry about the over head this will cause if we grab every node with these fields and process the check/update multiple times a day during potential peak hours.


Is hook_cron() our only option do you think?

Comment: very true, but you have better option to extend drupal core cron use [elysia cron](https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron). With this module you can get hold of each tasks individually, also you can have control over scheduling each task separately.
I am using elysia cron module try it, if the above answer does not fit your requirement because of cron,elysia cron will be the solution

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I think that should work.

Comment: Just remember drupal core cron works as per the site is accessed, if you need every thing right on time ;) set crontab on your server and so is elysia cron it can be configured easily to work both way.